# How can I get the src attributes of each image element with the same class in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can I get the src attributes of each image element with the same class and store it in an array to access it in JQuery?

Here is the html

```
<div id="preload">
  <img class="pre-img" src="images/img1.jpg">
  <img class="pre-img" src="images/img2.jpg">
  <img class="pre-img" src="images/img3.jpg">
</div>
```

and here is the jquery code

```
function preloadImages(){
    var image = $(".pre-img").toArray();
    for(var i=0; i < image.length; i++)
    {
        var path = image[i].attr('src');
        console.log(path);
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me where I'm doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function preloadImages(){
debugger;
    var image = $(".pre-img").toArray();
    for(var i=0; i < image.length; i++)
    {
        var path = image[i].src; // or may be this, $(image[i]).attr('src');
        console.log(path);
    }
}

preloadImages();
```

Note: You need a wrapper to access attr() method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuerys map function:

```
var imagePaths = $(".pre-img").map(function() {
    return this.src; //this refers to the DOM element, so you can simply access the property you want
}).get(); //.get() to convert the result to an array
```

Comment: This is returning undefined